# Why doesn't gvpr for with ARGV work?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, graphviz

I am trying my first steps with graphviz gvpr language:

```
BEGIN 
 {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < ARGC; ++i)
   {
    print(i);
    print(ARGV[i]);
   }

  for (ARGV[i])
   {
    print(i);
    print(ARGV[i]);
   }
 }
```

While the first old style for loop works as expected, the second one always results in a syntax error. Does ARGV not work with this style of for loop or whats the syntax error?

I am calling this with a string argument.